# Update mongoDB with todolist information?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js, axios

I have a todolist feature in my frontend, here is a demo: https://gyazo.com/a10fcd7c470439fe5cc703eef75b437f

It is all updated using an array in a Vue component and then using v-models to keep track of the data and change the UI to reflect that array.

When the user clicks 'send' i want it to send off the data to the database.

The issue im having is that i can't work out how to import newly created 'todos'(the text box and check box that is created when the + button is clicked) into the database.

This is what each todolist document looks like in my 'todolists' collection in the mongo:

```
{
    "_id":"5caca1498accb128c8974d56",
    "title":"todolist1 11111 11111 11111 11111",
    "userEmail":"test@gmail.com",
    "todos":[
        {
            "_id":"5caca1498accb128c8974d57",
            "description":"Get this done",
            "completed":true}
    ],
    "dateDue":"2019-04-07T18:24:31.207Z",
    "__v":0
}
```

The 'save' button in the demo has a v-on:click attribute that has a function named `saveTodoList()`, which then makes an axios post request to the route `/updateTodoList`

Feel free to ask any questions that will help you answer my question :)

Answer (score 0):

When a new todo is saved after clicking plus button, make a request on `/updateTodoList` with parent document's `_id`. So your request might look something like this:

POST `/updateTodoList`:

Body:

```
{ "_id": "5caca1498accb128c8974d56",
  "todo": {
     "description": "This is a newly added todo description",
     "completed": false
   }
}
```

Then, on the server side, parse this body object and update the document with matching `_id` and push the new todo into the document. Your query will look something like this:

```
todolist.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body._id}, { $push: {todos: req.body.todo } })
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

Each time you push a todo using above query, mongo inserts that element to the todos array. For pushing multiple todos in single query, use `$each` operator along with `$push`. Official documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#example-push-each).

Comment: In the body, how would i append multiple todos? And if i do this will it push all of the todos (including the old ones) to the document, or just the newly created ones?

Comment: Edited the answer with link to proper documentation